# Passing variables back from a function?

Tags: asp-classic

i am looking at some ancient code and there is the following line of code:

```
strResult = strResult + "<table>" & vbLf
        output = PrintTableHead("Field Office Code","1")
        strResult = strResult + PrintTableHead("Field Office Code","1")
        strResult = strResult + "<tr>" & vbLf


Function PrintTableHead( TheTitle ,  TheColSpan ) 

    strResult = "<tr><th colspan="
    strResult = strResult + TheColSpan
    strResult = strResult + " BGCOLOR=""#004D95"" align=center>" & vbLf
    strResult = strResult + "<font face=""Time New Roman"" color=""#ffffff"" SIZE=3>" & vbLf
    strResult = strResult + TheTitle
    strResult = strResult + "</font></th></tr>" & vbLf

End Function
```

when i try to debug strResult. it does not append the contents of the pIrntTableHead function. why isn't this working? how can i rewrite this to append correctly?

so after   `strResult = strResult + "<tr>" & vbLf` the value of strResult is still just :

> `"table><tr>"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function never returns its value. You'd need the following line just before the `End Function`.

```
PrintTableHead = strResult
```

Note that you should make sure strResult is declare locally within the function as well, to avoid overwriting the variable you are using in the calling code. The whole function would look like this:

```
Function PrintTableHead( TheTitle ,  TheColSpan ) 

    Dim strResult
    strResult = "<tr><th colspan="
    strResult = strResult + TheColSpan
    strResult = strResult + " BGCOLOR=""#004D95"" align=center>" & vbLf
    strResult = strResult + "<font face=""Time New Roman"" color=""#ffffff"" SIZE=3>" & vbLf
    strResult = strResult + TheTitle
    strResult = strResult + "</font></th></tr>" & vbLf
    PrintTableHead = strResult

End Function
```

Comment: thanks! i was trying "Return strResult" before, but was getting errors. let me give this a try! p.s. it worked :) thanks!